# Automation of row selection based on column value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file structured like this:

```
Key_Col Column Column
A       foo    bar
A       foo    bar
A       foo    bar
B       foo    bar
B       foo    bar
Z       foo    bar
Z       foo    bar
Z       foo    bar
Z       foo    bar
```

I want to select all of the rows that share the same Key_Col, and then copy and paste that into a new worksheet. For example, I want to select all three 'A' rows, both 'B' rows, and all 4 'Z' rows, and copy each into a separate worksheet.

I just used A, B, and Z as an example. In reality, there are several different values in the key column, and a variable number of each. I haven't found very many good VBA tutorials on Google. In any other programming language, I'd imagine I would just use a double for-loop, where the inner one loops while current_key equals initial_key, and then move on to the next unique key in the sequence.

Comment: possibly the best way to do it is to `apply filter` for each of `key value` separately and than copy results into new worksheet. You would need one `loop` for all keys and some code for filtering (where `macro recorder` will be helpful).

Comment: @pnuts - your link looks promising! I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably do it, some things to note:

- StartSelect is the row you want to start at.
- Pastesheet is the sheet index you want start pasting at.
- Sourcesheet is the sheet that has your data.
- It will run until it gets to an empty cell.
- If it runs out of sheets, it will create new empty ones.
- I've assumed you want column 1, to change it, change (startselect ,1) to your column.

  ```
  Dim StartSelect As Integer
  Dim EndSelect As Integer
  Dim PasteSheet As Integer
  Dim SourceSheet As Integer

  Sub Macro1()
  StartSelect = 1
  PasteSheet = 2
  SourceSheet = 1

  While Sheets(SourceSheet).Cells(StartSelect, 1) <> ""
      EndSelect = StartSelect
      While Sheets(SourceSheet).Cells(StartSelect, 1) = Sheets(SourceSheet).Cells((EndSelect+1), 1)
          EndSelect = EndSelect + 1
      Wend
      Sheets(SourceSheet).Rows(StartSelect & ":" & EndSelect).Copy
      If PasteSheet > Sheets.Count Then Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
      Sheets(PasteSheet).Paste
      PasteSheet = PasteSheet + 1
      StartSelect = (EndSelect + 1)
  Wend

  End Sub
  ```